# Share file audio Intent Android

Tags: java, android, android-intent, share

Hi i have this code but not work:

```
  Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
  sharingIntent.setType("audio/*");
  sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,
  Uri.fromFile(new File("http://mp3light.net/assets/songs/393000-393999/393375-see-you-again-feat-charlie-puth--1428288074.mp3")));
  startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent,"Share using"));
```

I would like to share a file format audio via Intent , by downloading the file from an mp3

Comment: Please explain your exact problem, and try to clean up your post a little bit.

Comment: `http://...` does not refer to a local path, and therefore you cannot use `File` with it, let alone `Uri.fromFile()`.

Answer (score 1):

Because you have pass file in URI.fromFile() instead of file's absolute path.

Check out my edited code.

```
Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
share.setType("audio/*");
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,Uri.parse("file:///"+mypath));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Sound File"));
break;
```

Comment: I can not use a file from a url , so am not applying too big ?

Answer (score 0):

I did not have enough points to comment on the original answer, but since it isn't accepted, I wanted to note that @Samir Bhatt has the correct answer for this, at least for me.

I had an issue with this, and this line from Samir's answer gave me my solution, I was missing "file://":

```
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,Uri.parse("file:///"+mypath));
```

Thanks!